# How to get rid of the extra line on jstree's root node

Tags: javascript

As you can see on the screenshot from a jstree,above the triangle on the first node there is an extra vertical dash line:

[image]

Anybody knows how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 5):

In the version of jsTree I'm using, v3.3.7, the following call removes the dots...

```
$('#tree').jstree({
    core: {
        data: jsonData, // Some JSON data
        themes: { dots: false }
    }
});
```

The [jsTree API documentation](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=$.jstree.defaults&f=$.jstree.defaults.core.themes.dots) has specifications about this call.

Answer (score 4):

With current version (3.3.3) you can remove dots directly by calling

```
$('#treeContainer').jstree().hide_dots()
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a very fancy solution but I did this:

1. Get the root node. I'm not sure if its the right way but I'm doing this:

   ```
   var root = tree.jstree("_get_node");
   ```
2. Find the `ins` element and change its background style:

   ```
   root.find("ins:first").css("background-position-x", "-18px");
   ```